# Why do edits made in attribute table not show in associated layer? QGIS 1.8.0

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, attribute-table, heat-map, editing

I have compiled a heat map layer to display over a background raster map. I discovered that the heat map layer was incorrectly positioned because I had made an error in the coordinate entry fields of the imported data table. I therefore selected the attribute table of the heatmap layer, toggled editing on and manually amended the coordinates to the correct format. I then clicked save edits. However, although the attribute table now shows the correct coordinates, the heatmap layer is still in it's original incorrect position. 
Is there a simple solution to this? I am hoping I do not have to amend the original excel spreadsheet and rejoin the table.

Comment: Did you edit the geometry or attribute values? If QGIS is similar to ArcGIS, they are two different things.

Comment: I only changed the co-ordinate values from 5 to 6 digit grid references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values in the attribute table are **not** the coordinates of the geometry. You can create attribute field data from the geometry, but it does not work the other way round.

If you change the values, you do not change the geometry; and if you move points manually, the values in the attribute table are not changed automatically.

You have to re-import the data again to get the geometry placed correctly. Or try http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/numericalVertexEdit/